# plot iris dataset using matplotlib.pyplot & ListedColormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, statistics, data-science

I wrote below code to plot sepal width vs. sepal length for the famous iris dataset. I think it's supposed to plot the dots with 3 different colors (for the 3 different labels: 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'), but it only plots all the dots with one same color.

How can I use the labels to plot the dots with three different colors?

[image: screenshot]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
print(list(iris.feature_names))
print (iris.target)
data = pd.DataFrame(iris.data)
data.columns = iris.feature_names
data['label'] = iris.target
data.head()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
cmap_bold = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF'])

# create a scatter plot of SEPAL WIDTH versus SEPAL LENGTH and color by SPECIES
plt.scatter(data['sepal length (cm)'], data['sepal width (cm)'], cmap=cmap_bold)
plt.title("sepal width vs sepal length")
plt.xlabel('x label')
plt.ylabel('y label')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Where did you think you used the labels for the plot?

Comment: Since the label names are not passed on to the scatter plot it is unable to distinguish the different classes

Comment: `plt.scatter(...., c=data['label'], ...)`